# mvn compilation issue while building jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins

My current jenkins project only works for freestyle jobs. I;ve adding functionality to work for MultiBranchWorkflowProject and hence, I've added workflow dependencies. I'm getting following error while building jenkins project using maven. 
There is not much information in the log. I am getting following error but I'm not sure how to debug. There is Could anyone help me out

```
15:48:31 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
15:48:31 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
15:48:31 [ERROR] Found 1 error and 10 warnings.
15:48:31 [INFO] 1 error
15:48:31 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
15:48:31 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:48:31 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
15:48:31 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:48:31 [INFO] Total time: 3.021 s
15:48:31 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-17T15:48:31-07:00
15:48:31 [INFO] Final Memory: 43M/1350M
15:48:31 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:48:31 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) on project upload: Compilation failure
15:48:31 [ERROR] Found 1 error and 10 warnings.
15:48:31 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
15:48:31 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) on project upload: Compilation failure
15:48:31 Found 1 error and 10 warnings.
15:48:31 
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
15:48:31    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:48:31    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15:48:31    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:48:31    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
15:48:31    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
15:48:31    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
15:48:31    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
15:48:31    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
15:48:31 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
15:48:31 Found 1 error and 10 warnings.
15:48:31 
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:970)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
15:48:31    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
15:48:31    ... 20 more
15:48:31 [ERROR] 
15:48:31 [ERROR] 
15:48:31 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
15:48:31 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
15:48:32 Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
15:48:32 Archiving artifacts
15:48:34 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
15:48:34 [BFA] No failure causes found
15:48:34 [BFA] Done. 0s
15:48:34 No emails were triggered.
15:48:34 Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks,
LifeIsButifool

Comment: Is there anything else before this error? The files are copied locally to the jenkins server. Wondering what would happen if you manually ran maven build process via cli. According to the link in the error it says this is just a generic error message the real error is located in one of the included plugins.

Comment: There's nothing informative before the error